# Why does this naive solution to catastrophic cancellation not work?

Tags: numerical-methods

I see on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation) that catastrophic cancellation is a phenomena where B~=A then A-B will have very high relative error compared to the true difference.

A quite naive solution occurred to me: why not just take: A-B~=(N*A-N*B)/N s.t. N>>1?
This would make the 'true difference' much larger and should therefore decrease the relative error of approximating A-B by a lot right?

Comment: The numbers are equal in the leading digits. These leading digits cancel under subtraction. This does not change if you multiply both with the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a typical case where `A` and `B` are floating point numbers of the form `M*(2^EXP)`. Catastrophic cancellation happens because M only has a limited number of bits, and M_A is approximately M_B so the high bits cancel. You only have a few significant bits left.

Now consider what happens is your solution, with N=16. That just performs the same calculation, except that the numbers now have the form `M*(2^(EXP+4))`. The problem is still M, not EXP.

You do have an additional problem, though, if `EXP+4` overflows. Then the result would be `INF-INF`, which is `NaN` : Not a Number

Comment: This is a good answer, but to play devils advocate what if N=1.99999?
Wouldn't that at least roughly halve the relative error?

Comment: @profPlum: That's just `0.999999*2`. You first risk one bit due to rounding (this time the lowest bit of M), then you increment both exponents. You still lose the highest bits of M in cancellation.

Comment: Are you saying even though it is less than 2 that it would still increase the exponent?

Comment: @profPlum: Well, except for edge case inputs like 1.000000 and 8.000000 of course.  But for an input like pi or sqrt(17), yes.

Comment: the "high bits cancel" argument is incorrect if `A` and `B` are floating point numbers; see the Sterbenz lemma.

Answer (score 3):

> I see on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation) that catastrophic cancellation is a phenomena where B~=A then A-B will have very high relative error compared to the true difference.

That's not what catastrophic cancellation is, and that's not what Wikipedia says.

In fact, if A and B are even modestly nearby floating-point numbers, close enough that B/2 ≤ A ≤ B, then by the [Sterbenz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterbenz_lemma), A − B is a floating-point number too and so floating-point subtraction A ⊖ B = fl(A − B) will compute A − B exactly with *zero* error.

Catastrophic cancellation happens when you don't have A and B themselves—instead you have *approximations* A′ and B′ to true values A and B, and you want the difference A − B.
These approximations might arise for many reasons: from measurement error, from series truncation, from rounding, etc.

Even if you can compute the exact difference A′ − B′ (and in floating-point arithmetic, when A′ and B′ are close enough, you can!), the relative error of the difference of *approximations* A′ − B′ can be very large—it's inversely proportional to the difference A − B of the true values.  That's catastrophic cancellation.

Specifically, the relative error of A′ − B′ from A − B is |A − B|/|A − B|, where  = (A − A′)/A and  = (B − B′)/B, so that || is the relative error of A′ from A and || is the relative error of B′ from B.

> I quite naive solution occurred to me: why not just take: A-B~=(NA-NB)/N s.t. N>>1? This would make the 'true difference' much larger and should therefore decrease the relative error of approximating A-B by a lot right?

This doesn't accomplish anything.

If you have *approximations* A′ and B′ and you are able to compute (NA′ − NB′)/N = A′ − B′ exactly, well, the result would still be subject to catastrophic cancellation.
But it's worse, because your suggestion is to compute (N⊙A′ ⊖ N⊙B′)⊘N = fl(fl(fl(NA′) − fl(NB′))/N), incurring many additional rounding errors (unless N is a power of the floating-point radix), and possibly incurring overflow or underflow as well.

**The only way to avoid catastrophic cancellation is to avoid trying to subtract approximations of nearby quantities.**
For example:

- Instead of measuring two sticks with a ruler and subtracting the lengths you measured, lay the sticks side by side with one end of each stick aligned and measure the distance between the unaligned ends directly.
- Instead of computing exp(x) = 1 + x + x²/2 + x³/3! + x⁴/4! + ⋯ and then subtracting 1 from it when you want exp(x) − 1 for x near 0, rewrite it as exp(x) − 1 = x + x²/2 + x³/3! + x⁴/4! + ⋯ and compute that directly without subtraction.

  - In a math library, you can do this with the `expm1` procedure.
- Instead of computing (1 − fl(cos(t)))/2 for t near 0 with a table of cosines in a [historic math library](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/trig-warning), compute fl(haversin(t)) with a [table of (logarithmic) haversines](https://archive.org/details/logarithmictrigo00hedriala/page/122/mode/2up) (or use `sin(t/2)**2` in a modern math library).

---

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72189078) is wrong and gives a dangerous misconception about the relation between floating-point arithmetic and catastrophic cancellation:

> Catastrophic cancellation happens because M only has a limited number of bits, and M_A is approximately M_B so the high bits cancel.

Catastrophic cancellation does not happen because of limited number of bits in the *output*—the Sterbenz lemma proves that the output of *floating-point subtraction* is exact when the inputs are close enough!

Catastrophic cancellation happens when the *inputs* to the subtraction are themselves approximations with some error—again, whether that error is from measurement, series truncation, rounding, *etc.*

Even if you had *infinitely many bits* in your representation of A′, B′, and A′ − B′, using A′ − B′ as an approximation to A − B would still have relative error proportional to 1/(A − B).
In technical terms, subtraction is [ill-conditioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) at nearby inputs, just like log is ill-conditioned near 1.

**Catastrophic cancellation is a fundamental property of the mathematical subtraction operation, independent of floating-point representations, and it applies whether or not the output of subtraction is rounded.**

Answer (score 1):

We need to distinguish between the error when subtracting floating point numbers, and the error when subtracting two numbers which are approximated by their two closest floating point representables.

If A and B are floating point numbers with A/2 <= B <= 2A, then the subtraction A - B is exact. This is the [Sterbenz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterbenz_lemma). So if you were thinking that A and B are floating point representables, the premise of the question is incorrect.

However, if you imagined that A and B are arbitrary real numbers, then they must be approximated by floating point numbers a and b, according to the rounding model a = A(1+δ), b = B(1+υ), where δ<=μ ν<=μ where μ is the unit round off.

The relative error is |(a - b) - (A-B)|/|A - B| = |Aδ - Βν|/|A-B| <= μ|A+B|/|A-B|. If you rescale all these quantities, you also rescale the error, i.e.,

|Na - Nb - (NA-NB)|/|NA - NB| = |NAδ - NΒν|/|NA-NB| = |Aδ - Βν|/|A-B|.

Comment: Ya that's a good point from the math perspective as well.